# Highlighting set of specific keywords in gvim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have tried highlighting specific words by adding them in .vimrc, colorscheme file and also in syntax.vim(I changed one at a time, not altogether).

```
syn match mygroupwords '\c\<\(-word1\|-word2\)'            
hi  def link mygroupwords colo_words12                                      
hi colo_words12  guifg=red1   gui=bold  guibg=white
```

But somehow it seems to be getting overwritten by default syntax highlighting

i need to highlight keywords irrespective of color-scheme or file-type which have following words- 
Ex; **-word1 , -word2**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

#### explanation of your failed attempts

A *colorscheme* just provides color definitions for predefined *highlight groups*; that's the wrong place for actual syntax matches! `~/.vimrc` is the first configuration that is read; if a filetype is detected and a corresponding syntax script is loaded, that will override your syntax definition.

#### syntax extensions

If your desired highlightings are extensions to an existing syntax, you can place `:syntax match` commands in a syntax script in the *after directory*. For example, to extend Python syntax, put it in `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`. That may still fail if the original syntax obscures the match; sometimes, this can be solved via `containedin=...`

#### independent marks

If your highlightings are independent of syntax and filetype, there's a different built-in mechanism: `:match` (and `:2match`, and additional variants via `:call matchadd(...)`):

```
:match mygroupwords /\c\<\(-word1\|-word2\)/
```

This goes on top of (and is independent of) syntax highlighting. However, it is *local to the current window*. So, if you put this into your `.vimrc`, it will only affect the first window (but any files viewed in there). To apply this globally to window splits and tab pages, you have to use `:autocmds`. It's not trivial to get this totally right. If you need such a full solution, have a look at my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666); this supports multiple colors, allows presetting with `:[N]Mark /{pattern}/` (similar to `:match`), and highlights in all windows.

Comment: Hi Ingo Karkat , I tried placing  those syntax match commands in syntax extensions. I couldn't highlight those words.

Comment: Depending on the syntax, that can still fail; see my edit. Actually, I only added that paragraph for completeness, I thought you're after independent marks?!

Comment: I dont want to use plugins, i just want to highlight those words in .sh files.